# start exe as non admin from admin exe

Tags: c++, windows-vista, uac

When my app updates it needs admin rights and pops the uac prompt up and this is all good. However when it restarts it self its still in admin mode and thus every thing it does has admin rights. The problem comes when the next time the app is started its a normal user and thus cant read any of the files that where made before.

How do a start an exe as a normal user from an admin priviladge exe?

Visual studio 2008
vista / win 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista-security/VistaElevator.aspx) is an article that describes how to start non-elevated process from an elevated one.

Comment: ta i ended up using http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista-security/createprocessexplorerleve.aspx